# Will they allow me to collect my luggage at the connection airport and not taking the connecting flight?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, connecting-flights, hidden-city-ticketing

My flight is from Toronto to Istanbul through Vienna. Now I need to stay in Vienna and decided not the take the connecting flight. 
First, do they let me to cancel the connecting flight?
Second,if I am not allowed to cancel it, can I just-while checking in- ask the agent at the airport to put Vienna as my final destination so I can collect it at Vienna, and tell them that I am not gonna take the connecting flight?(I am OK with paying any penalty for that... but would they let me do that?)

Comment: If you booked a return flight originating in Istanbul and don’t show up, the airline will cancel your entire return trip.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually against airline rules but some people do so to get a lower fare. That  is known as *hidden city ticketing*. For it to work, you should not check-in luggage and only do it for one-way or on the last leg, because any subsequent flights would get automatically cancelled by the airline.

What you need to do change the itinerary with the airlines. Most of them will be happy to do so for a fee plus the fare difference. The exact fees and amount depends on the rules of the fare you  purchased. Assuming you have a return flight too, you would have to pay to change it as well, although if you do it once for both, the fees for changing will be charged once.

Comment: This is actually the return flight and Vienna to Istanbul is the last route of the whole ticket. So if I ask them is it feasible for them at the check-in to , despite the ticket final destination which is Istanbul- put VIenna on the luggage tag as the final destination? Or my only option is to not check in any luggage?

Comment: Would the airline cancel that last route of my ticket, and of course I will pay the fee  differences and any penalty...I am just worried they might say I must either cancel the whole route from Toronto to Istanbul or take the whole flight . ??

Comment: Usually that is at the discretion of the agent and is called *short-checking*. If your connection is short, they will usually not allow it since they will consider it possible that you will do hidden city ticketing. If you do not check any luggage, then you will most likely be able to get away with it. The only possibility of issue is they for some reason, they decide to reroute you through a different city since their agreement is to take you to Istanbul, not Vienna.

Comment: It is unlikely they will not let you change your ticket at all. It is in their interest to get fees from your change, so that is not much of a possibility. Conceivably, they *could* but it would be rather surprising.